# why feed section in social networking sites are similar?

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, design, user-research, usability-testing

Why is that every social networking sites have feeds page similar. Most of them use card structure for their feeds page. I just want to know the reason behind such use case. I thought every Social networking sites had mobile in their mind before they started building for the web ( it will be easier for the users to switch between mobile and web ) Can anyone help?

[image: Quora Feeds Page]

[image: Google Plus Feeds Page]

Answer (score 1):

All of the sites look similar because designs that catch on tend to get copied.  There are a couple of main reasons:

- When something new and trendy appears and becomes popular, other companies try to "keep up" by doing something similar.
- Once something becomes an established paradigm, it also becomes easy for users to understand and use.

But **there is no inherent reason why a card-based feed, or even the concept of a feed had to exist.**  This is one possible way of structuring information among many.  If some early pioneering social networking site had invented something else, we might all be using that now.

Comment: Did mobile view have any impact on this feed design structure?

Comment: I'd say that the reason is because people (actually, read: business-oriented world, among which social networks are perceived as a cash-cow - whether it's an objective truth or not) are obsessed over having a social network, not of inventing something new, in particular such "unimportant" thing as UI.

Comment: @GunaSeelan Facebook's activity feed was launched in 2006, before mobile web really took off.  Probably not a big consideration then.  Surely mobile was a factor in subsequent development of the concept.  But why do you ask about mobile with this specific feature?  It's not clear to me.

Comment: @dan1111 Because we are building something similar( for Mobile and Web ) . So before we take a different approach( on Feeds page design ) so I wanted some clear thought.  Can the feeds design be different in Mobile and Web. I thought design should be similar so that people won't have any difficulty navigating it. Correct me If I am wrong